# Format sms messages in Clickatell

Tags: c#, clickatell

We are sending sms messages to the registered users via the system using Clickatell API. I got a requirement of formatting the SMS messages as follows. The objective is to deliver a user friendly SMS message with some information. The format goes as follows;

Dear xxxxxxxxxxxx,

xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx xxx. xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx, xxxx xxxxxx xx xxx.
xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xx xxx.

Yours faithfully,
XXXX XXXX, 
XXXXX Manager
E test@domain.com

Is there any way of formatting a sms as displayed. The receiver should get the sms in above format. I want to set the text in above format before it send to the API

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to create line breaks/new lines in your message text.

How you do that would depend on which API you are using.

If you can tell me what API you are using, i can tell you how to do it.

For the HTTP API, you just send a new line character (\n) - the urlencoded value for that is %0A